# Simplest DIY datepicker and timepicker for a Metro app (c# & XAML)

Tags: c#, xaml

I am working on a Metro app, and as far as I know there is no datepicker control available ATM. In my app the user is working with dates, and I am looking for a way to make this less painfull for the user.

What would be the best way to go about it? Anybody have a nice custom control sample they would like to share?

I have the same problem with graphs, but I am hoping to get an access code to Teleriks preview to their Win8 controls, but I couldnt see any date or timepickers there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is not a WinRT DatePicker as explained in this [MSDN answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winappswithcsharp/thread/28515145-d7ef-4625-bca4-6e45c2350cf6). [Tim Heuer](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/05/31/introducing-callisto-a-xaml-toolkit-for-metro-apps.aspx) and some are working on some simple WinRT components. You can find their work, called [Callisto](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto), on [Github](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto). A DatePicker looks to be next on the list, but they could always use help as well. The best place to start would be the Windows Phone 7 DatePicker. You can download the [source from Codeplex](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets#).

Answer (score 0):

[Telerik has now released the beta of their windows 8 controls](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-metro/overview.aspx), one of them being a datepicker! Problem solved :)

Comment: I can't see how a commercial, closed-source product can be an answer to your need for a DIY custom control sample.

Comment: It was free when I downloaded it (beta) but I've changed the accepted answer now. Thank you for the comment!